# Python spaCy custom tokenizer suffix and infix problem

Tags: python, regex, string, spacy, python-re

I'm working on adding rules to the 'en_core_web_sm' spaCy nlp model's tokeniser, to correctly tokenise the string below:
`s = "This string M=20kg/H=200mm"`
into tokens ['This', 'string', 'M=', '20', 'kg', '/', 'H=', '200', 'mm']
But having '/' as an infix, and 'kg' as a suffix right before the infix complicates the situation. How can I make the right tokenisation rules?

This is my code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
s = "This string M=20kg/H=200mm"
# Update suffix search 
from spacy.lang.char_classes import UNITS
unit_suffix_regex = r"(?<=[\d])({u})".format(u=UNITS)
suffixes = nlp.Defaults.suffixes
suffixes.append(unit_suffix_regex)
suffix_regex = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_regex.search
```

But it still gives the wrong results, and tokenises the string above into:

```
('TOKEN', 'This')
('TOKEN', 'string')
('TOKEN', 'M=20kg')
('INFIX', '/')
('TOKEN', 'H=200')
('SUFFIX', 'mm')
```

If I modify s into `s = "This string M=20kg /H=200mm"`, then I get this output:

```
('TOKEN', 'This')
('TOKEN', 'string')
('TOKEN', 'M=20')
('SUFFIX', 'kg')
('TOKEN', '/H=200')
('SUFFIX', 'mm')
```

And 'kg' gets recognised as a suffix (I think this also happens without me adding the rule)

What is the problem here? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The tokenizer algorithm isn't recursive. It looks for prefixes and suffixes, then it looks for infixes, and then it stops. It doesn't look again for prefixes and suffixes after splitting on infixes. A full description of the algorithm: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#how-tokenizer-works

One option, if the units like `kg` are easy to distinguish based on context, is to add them as infixes, but you need to watch for confusion with non-unit uses, e.g. "gin**kg**o" vs. "3**kg**/x".

Another option is to write a custom component that uses the retokenizer (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#retokenization) to post-process the tokenization. This is more flexible and can handle cases that the tokenizer algorithm doesn't support.